# Use of limits of sequences for the non-existence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, sequence-of-function

Let $f(x) = x +1$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) = x- 1$ for $x < 0$. I want to use the limits to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ does not exist. I tried with using $x_n = \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ (as $n \rightarrow \infty$) which leads to $f(x) \rightarrow \pm 1$ (as $x \rightarrow 0$). Is this enough to show the desired conclusion ?

Edit : The following excerpt is from Wade's [Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132296381) book. I wonder how the expression form for $f(x_n)$ was followed, whether it's a typo or not.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. You'll need to show that $f(x_n)$ diverges, which is not quite what you proved here. To do that, you'll have to find an $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ has two different subsequences that converge to different limits. Hint: Try $x_n=(-1)^n/n$.

Comment: With $x_n=1/n$, $f(x_n)\rightarrow 1$. On the other hand, with $x_n=-1/n$, $f(x_n)\rightarrow -1$. Hence $\lim f$ does not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought is close to being correct. Per your $x_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$, it is not correct because that is only one sequence and $f(x_n) \to 1$. Perhaps you mean $x_n = \pm \dfrac{1}{n}$, but this means you essentially have $2$ sequences $x_n = \dfrac{1}{n}, x'_n = -\dfrac{1}{n}$ and in this case it is true. In general, you simply need to choose  $2$ distinct sequences that converge to $0$ and the sequences obtained by applying $f$ to both sequences converge to $2$ different values, i.e diverge. You could argue, by using the sequence $x_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$ which converges to $0$. However, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ does not converge to any value. The reason for that is it has $2$ subsequences $f(x_{2n})$ converges to $1$, and $f(x_{2n+1})$ converges to $-1$. This all means that there is no limit at $x = 0$ of $f$.

Comment: thank you. When calculating $f(x_n)$, for which $f$ value we need to use; $x \geq 0$ or $x < 0$ ?

Comment: $f(x_{2n+1}) = f(\frac{-1}{2n+1}) = -\frac{1}{2n+1}-1$, and $f(x_{2n}) = \frac{1}{2n} + 1$.

Comment: Thank you. I found another explanation in Wade's Analysis book, which I've added in the post itself. I quite don't see how $f(x_n)$ has the given form.

Comment: That's great though. I too read some of the books like the one you quoted. I have several analysis books and I keep reading them back and forth.